# Is inline video supported in iPhone's Safari in iOS6?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, mobile-safari, html5-video

I'm not able to find anything that confirms or denies a rumor I heard that iPhones running iOS 6 can display video inline in Safari.

Is this still just an iPad feature?

Answer (score 1):

No. Video on the iPhone (iOS 6) still pops full-screen. I suspect this will not change any time soon as it's considered a feature, rather than a limitation.

Comment: maybe animated gifs + `<audio>`? :)

Comment: How `canvas` performs in iPhone?

Comment: canvas can be quite quick on the iPhone 4+. It is no where near the performance of a desktop canvas, but you can draw hundreds of polygons per frame. One thing to note on iPhone is that canvas performs much better when the page is not scaled.

Comment: One more interesting thing we can do for inline videos is what Apple did in their new products pages. Checkout for example iPad mini product page. They just swap jpeg images rapidly. Those "videos" are not really video

Comment: @Mohsen correct, but they are VERY heavy when compared to h.264 video, and can't easily be synced to sound.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone and iPod seem just about the only devices/browsers that force fullscreen video playback in Safari (and in apps that make use of its unmodified WebView)

You can work around this issue by simulating the playback by *skimming* the video instead of actually `.play()`'ing it.

I wrote a module that takes care of playing the video and synchronizing it to the audio (but it also works on videos without a sound track): [iphone-inline-video](https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video)